# How to change a button shape style at runtime?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I am developing an app in java, android studio, where the user can choose the style color of the app.

With most components just use the `.setBackground(colorUser);`

The problem is in my buttons.

My buttons are all rounded, I created a shape for that.

My shape is in other file...

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorJetway" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="80dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="80dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="80dp"
        android:topRightRadius="80dp" />

</shape>

<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdc"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"

            android:layout_marginEnd="205dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btns_border"
            android:onClick="btnAdicionar_click"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtQuantidade" />
```

That way if at runtime I make `mybutton.setBackground(colorUser)` my button loses its style ... it will have no rounded edges.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not exactly what you are looking for.
However using the [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) component it is very simple to have rounded buttons.

Just use `app:cornerRadius` to define the corner radius and `app:backgroundTint` to change the background color.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:backgroundTint="@color/myselector"
    app:cornerRadius="xxdp"
    .../>
```

You can programmatically change these values using:

```
button.setCornerRadius(...);
button.setBackgroundTintList(..);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your colors is limited you can create some drawables with the colors you want.

for example :

blackButton.xml :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/black" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="80dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="80dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="80dp"
    android:topRightRadius="80dp" />
```

whiteButton.xml :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/white" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="80dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="80dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="80dp"
    android:topRightRadius="80dp" />
```

and when you want change your button's background just use `button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blackButton))` or `button.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.whiteButton))`